# Video Streamer using m3u8 file in android

Tags: android, video-streaming

Hi I'm trying to play a video streamer but its always prompt "Can't play this video" i don't know why is like that I'm following [this]http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/ tutorial. 
I already put in android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

but still its not working.
I have an error says "Unable to create media player"
 Can anybody help me please? 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solve the problem :)
I put the

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

first before the application tag in android manifest